# Get column and table name from a list from a model in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate mapping XML for class A:

```
<class name="com.example.A" table="table_a">
  <id name="id" column="id">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="foo" table="bar"/>
  <list name="bs" table="table_b">
    <key column="kee">
    <index column="indx">
    <many-to-many column="bss" class="com.example.B"/>
  </list>
</class>
```

I can get the table name of class A as following:

```
configuration.getClassMapping(A.getName())
    .getTable()
    .getName();
```

I can also get the column name of property "foo" as following:

```
Column col = (Column) configuration
    .getClassMapping(clazz.getName())
    .getProperty(propertyName)
    .getColumnIterator().next();
col.getName();
```

However I don't know how to get:

1. the table name of the list "bs" `//"table_b"`
2. the name of the "key" column of the list "bs" `//"kee"`
3. the name of the "index" column of list "bs" `//"indx"`
4. the column name of the many-to-many relationship with class B `//"bss"`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to question 1,2,3:

(1) the table name of the list "bs" //"table_b"

```
return collection.getCollectionTable().getName();
```

(2) the name of the "key" column of the list "bs" //"kee"

```
return ((Column) collection.getKey().getColumnIterator().next()).getName();
```

(3) the name of the "index" column of list "bs" //"indx"

```
org.hibernate.mapping.List list = (org.hibernate.mapping.List) collection;
return ((Column) collection.getIndex().getColumnIterator().next()).getName();
```

Still have no answer for 4.